# Multithreaded Core Data object has empty properties on main thread after saving on background thread

Tags: swift, core-data, ios10

As shortly described in the title, after I save an object on background thread, its properties are empty on the main thread, such as strings being `""`, numbers `0` etc.

Here's some code!

User class:

```
@objc(User)
class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: Int32
    @NSManaged var email: String
}
```

UserRepository where the actual save is happening:

```
func saveUser(fromJSON json: Any, onSuccess: ((User) -> Void)?, onFailure: ((Error) -> Void)?) {
    dataManager.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in
        context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
        let user = self.userFactory.user(fromJSON: json, inContext: context)
        // print(user.id) and print(user.email) output correct data
        do {
            try context.save()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // print(user.id) and print(user.email) show 0 and ""
                onSuccess?(user)
            }
        } catch let error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                onFailure?(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `dataManager` is configured like this:

```
class CoreDataManager {

    private let modelName: String

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: modelName)
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

            container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
            container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
        })
        return container
    }()

    init(modelName: String) {
        self.modelName = modelName
    }
}
```

I'm guessing `userFactory` is not that important, but for the sake of completeness:

```
class UserFactory {

    func user(fromJSON json: Any, inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> User {
        guard
            let jsonDictionary = json as? [String: Any?],
            let userDictionary = jsonDictionary["user"] as? [String: Any?],
            let id = userDictionary["id"] as? Int32,
            let email = userDictionary["email"] as? String
        else {
            fatalError("Could not parse User object.")
        }

        let user = User(context: context)
        user.id = id
        user.email = email
        return user
    }
}
```

Please see the comments in the snippets above in regards to print statements which point out the places where user properties are fine and where they show `0` and `""`.

I'm aware I can't pass NSManagedObjects between threads, but even if I try fetching the user object in the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block using its `objectID` (`NSManagedObjectID`), user properties are still empty.

I guess I'm doing something wrong, but can't put a finger on it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: When you say `user.id = id` and `user.email = email`, have you confirmed that these are not `nil`?

Comment: Yes, I have - in the guard statement above, in the factory.

Comment: Oh yes, I see, silly me, sorry. - By the way I really like that way of formatting the `guard` list. I'm going to adopt it in my own code!

Comment: Thank you, glad you liked it! Yeah, I think it's very easy to read when there's more than 1 statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, I think, is that Core Data is not thread safe. I know you know this - that, after all, is why you created a special background context - but it has very strict implications. You are saying:

```
dataManager.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
    let user = self.userFactory.user(fromJSON: json, inContext: context)
    do {
        try context.save()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(user) // <--
```

You can't do that. You're still talking about the `user` you saved into the background context, but you've switched threads. No. You cannot talk about this `user` from two different threads.

Once you are on the main thread, the only way you may talk to Core Data is through the *main* context. You need to *fetch* the user out, by its id, from the *main* context. Now you can look to see how it is populated.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background. It says in big letters, "Do not pass NSManagedObject instances between queues". But that, it seems to me, is exactly what you _are_ doing.

Comment: Thank you @matt! Yes, it actually required a separate `NSFetchRequest` with `user.id` (previously stored in a variable). I hoped it would be enough to just go `privateContext.object(withID: user.objectID)` or `viewContext.object(withID: user.objectID)`. It doesn't seem optimal if I store e.g. 1000 objects and then have to re-query them right away from Core Data - but I guest it is what it is. Thanks again for your time! Cheers :)

Comment: @imilakovic, may I know how you fix it. I met the same issue as I first using bakground context in CoreData, I save things in CoreData in background context and push back to main thread to reflect it on UI change. But UI(tableView) shows nothing though the property has the value.

Comment: @ChuckZHB I don't think I ever did. I switched to Realm for that project :) However, one idea that should do the trick is to treat CoreData objects just as persistence objects - and then, when you fetch them on the background thread, you could map those to plain Swift objects (possibly structs?) which won't care about the thread they're on. Then you can pass those mapped objects back to the main thread and update your tableView. Hope this works/helps!

Comment: @imilakovic thanks for the replying. Well, I did a lot of searching on the internet about it. And fortunately, I could combine those stuff pice by pice and bring out the solution. Generally, the correct way to do the multi-threading thing in Core Data, which way Apple advised is to use private queue context and subclass it to the main queue context. This way we could transmit the change from background queue to main queue. If you still get interest, I gave a code example in my question `https://stackoverflow.com/a/68031628/10158398`.